# Is there a difference between ConfigurationManager.AppSettings and Properties.Settings.Default?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, properties, configurationmanager

In Visual Studio 2015, in C#, is there a difference between ConfigurationManager.AppSettings and Properties.Settings.Default

```
var a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BackupTime"];
var b = Properties.Settings.Default.BackupTime;
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an answer (would have left a comment but am sadly lacking in reputation) but I came across this post while facing an issue where they are quite plainly different.  I can't seem to find any information on the internal architecture of AppSettings.

I'm in Visual Studio 2017, writing a Windows service using .NET 4.6.  The service would fail when trying to access ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"] but calling Properties.Settings.Default.Key worked without issue.

That being said, I have no idea why they behave differently.